# Creating and Deleting Created Element Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, removechild, createelement

Suppose...
I have a **Create Button** and this **Create Button** creates **Block level Element** every time Create Button is **clicked** ... I mean If you click Create Button 100 times, it will create block Element 100 times.
Into that **Block element**, I have a **delete button**.

Now what I want, is when **that delete button** is clicked of its respected Parent element ... that **Parent element** should be removed completely with whatever content into it.

So ***clicking delete button of that particular parent element***, only ***that particular element should be removed*** and there should be no disturbance to others.
Hope you understand what I am trying to say.

I am actually creating a front end project challenged from Frontend mentor, here is the link https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/interactive-comments-section-iG1RugEG9

I tried giving ids to them but after the first time either no other elements are removed or all elements get removed. My problem might confuse you so please tell me how to create that mechanism mentioned above.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can actually help out

Comment: As mentioned above, please read and follow: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could just add dynamically ids for each block and append buttons with click event passing the dynamic id as parameter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this is not at all how you ask a proper question here. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), make yourself acquainted with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and **specifically** [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe take a look at `addEventListener()`, `event.target` and `element.closest()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delegate from container. Here I use `id="comments"`
2. give a class to button.
3. if the block element contains the button, just do this, assuming the block element is given `class="comment"`

   ```
   document.getElementById("comments").addEventHandler("click", e => { 
     const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); 
     if (tgt && tgt.matches(".delete")) tgt.closest("div.comment").remove();
   })
   ```